# Python Pandas - Dataset with many columns - want to iterate over each column, add row values to new list only from fields that are not null

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, for-loop

I have a dataset that I am inhering of website logs that basically adds a new series of columns based on the number of pages visited.  For example, if someone went to 2 pages on our website we'd have something like: visit_id, url_1, visit_datetime_1, url_2, visit_datetime_2.  The problem is that some people visit just one page, and some visit 14.  I want to simply this.  See below for my current format and desired output.  I guess I just don't understand how I will go through each column, when the number of fields are not always consistent (but the column names WILL be consistent: visit_id is a unique identifier, url_x, visit_datetime_x).  I'm stumped.

Just to be clear below, visit_id 1000 visited 3 pages, 2000 visited 1 page, and 3000 visited 2 pages.

[image]

I've just never done anything like this before in Pandas and I'm just at a roadblock.  I've gotten this far, which isn't far, but at least shows I'm trying.  All help is appreciated.

```
visit_ids = []
urls = []
visit_datetimes = []

dataset = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
df = pd.DataFrame(dataset)

for colname in df.iteritems():
    
    #do something to add to list
```

Comment: Is possible share Current format like text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split last numbers after `_` to `MultiIndex` and reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')

df1 = df.set_index('visit_id')
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.rsplit('_', n=1, expand=True)

df1 = df1.stack().reset_index()
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked.  Maybe it was much more simple than I expected.  I ran this line by line and I think I understand now.  Thank you! As soon as it will let me, I will check this off as answered.